# Move files from Document Center to Record Center in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, records-management, records-center, document-center

My client has SharePoint 2019 and they want their Record center separate from the Document Center.

The file hierarchy/structure for both will look exactly the same.  (Same names for subsites, libraries and folders in both).

When I have a file in the document center in the following path: `DocumentCenter/01 Policies/01_11 Human Capital` and the user declares it as a record, I want the file to move automatically to `RecordCenter/01 Polices/01_11 Human Capital` location as a record.

Is something like this possible, or is there any other suggestions to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried using Power Automate? Maybe it will do the trick.